# Share one folder with sample files for many unit test projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create 1 folder with sample files, for example .bmp files. Now I have 3 unit test projects. How to move files from this folder to output directory of each unit testing project?

I was searching for answer on the web, but looks like this simple problem have very complicated solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to do this would be to put your files into a portable class library and reference them in the projects you need the files in. The assets will then be copied to the respective output folders.

This will only work in Visual Studio 2012 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate, not the Express Version. Also your project has to be on .NET 4.5.

See [Portable Class Libraries on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) for further reference.